# How to get the wrapper's id or class of a string

Tags: javascript, string, tags

```
<span id="myId" class="myClass">Sample text</span>
```

I would like to get the id or class of a particular string in an html page by using text value, in this case **"Sample text"**. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: What is a wrapper? Are you searching for the parent element in DOM?

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, it's very simple:

```
var searchText = 'Sample text',
    $element = $('span:contains(' + searchText ')'),
    id = $element.attr('id'),
    className = $element.attr('class');
```

It's not so concise with strictly vanilla JS.

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'),
    element,
    text,
    re = /Sample Text/,
    // IE doesn't support textContent, FF doesn't support innerText
    prop = document.body.innerText ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'; 

for (var i=0; i<spans.length; i++)
{
    if (re.test(spans[i][prop]))
    {
        span = spans[i];
        break;
    }
}

var id, className;
if (span)
{
    id = span.id;
    className = span.className;
}
```

Comment: great answer, however, I was hoping for the one who would spent some extra time on a non-jQuery answer. Why? Because it is possible.

Comment: Should be class not className